# How to absolute position imageless corners with css

Tags: css, rounded-corners

I'm looking for a way to absolute position the four corners used in the following css style. I tried the following, but that wasn't the right one.

```
.rbottom{display:block; background:#f57f20; position:absolute; top:500px;}
```

This is the original css:

```
.container5 {background:#666666; color:#fff; margin:0 15px;}

.rbottom{display:block; background:#f57f20;}
.rtop{display:block; background:#eaeade;}
.rtop *, .rbottom *{display: block; height: 1px; overflow: hidden; background:#666666;}
.r1{margin: 0 5px}
.r2{margin: 0 3px}
.r3{margin: 0 2px}
.r4{margin: 0 1px; height: 2px}

.rl1 {margin: 0 0 0 5px; }
.rl2 {margin: 0 0 0 3px; }
.rl3 {margin: 0 0 0 2px; }
.rl4 {margin: 0 0 0 1px; height: 2px;}

.rr1 {margin: 0 5px 0 0; }
.rr2 {margin: 0 3px 0 0; }
.rr3 {margin: 0 2px 0 0; }
.rr4 {margin: 0 1px 0 0; height: 2px;}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not entirely clear what you're asking. The way to position something absolutely in CSS is to use the `position: absolute` property, and then specify where that element should be positioned, e.g.:

```
.foo {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 100px;
}
```

On the other hand, it sounds like you're trying to implement CSS rounded corners. If you don't mind your corners being square (not rounded) in IE, you can use the browser-specific CSS3 rounded corner properties:

```
.bar {
    border: 1px solid #000000;
    border-radius: 3px;
    -moz-border-radius: 3px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
}
```

Which should work on Firefox, Safari, and Google Chrome, but not any version of IE.

Comment: Might want to add the non-proprietary `border-radius` as well, in case Opera or IE decide to support it in the future (Chrome does already, but nothing else AFAIK).

Comment: Good point. The cross-browser support for CSS is a truly sorry state of affairs...

Answer (score 0):

assuming that `.container5` is the wrapper for all the corners, have you tried to add `position: relative;` to it?